# android Libgdx particle editor special line

Tags: libgdx, editor, particles

As we all know that the particle editor give us a explosive particle line . However , what I need is a particle move from around point to the point I clicked . How can I realize this?

Answer (score 0):

Just take a "Point particle" and change the position over time to the clicked point while the `ParticleEffect`is running. Thats all you need todo. A simple approach would be to create a class which holds the component `ParticleEffect`, an target position and extends `Actor`. Inside of the `act(float delta)` you update the position of the `Actor` into the direction of the target by an speedvalue multiplied with the delta time. Don't forget to update the postion of the ParticleEffect. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void act2(float delta) {
    direction = this.pos - this.target; //both are vector2
    direction.nor();
    this.setPosition(direction.x*delta*velocity, direction.y*delta*velocity); 
}

@Override
public void draw2(Batch batch, float alpha) {
    emitter.setPosition(getX(), getY());
    emitter.draw(batch);
}
```

Comment: It's really hard ! Would you please give a demo project ?

Comment: I already gave you everything you need for an Actor which moves an Effect from one position to an other position. Simply do what i wrote down. Create one object of that class add it to a `Stage` which you draw inside of your main loop and pass the target position to it. I wont give you a whole working project. If you don't understand the process of adding a `Actor` to a `Stage` and so on, take a look into this http://steigert.blogspot.de/ . It gives you a start and you can go further from it. Try to understand how things move and so on.

Comment: I did it with Action . Thanks